# how to put c# in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I have a button that on click it's send me to a javascript function, in the function I have the code:

```
document.getElementById("div_show").innerHTML = 
    "<br /><div class='font-1'>View Messages:</div><br /><br /><div><%=Display %></div><br /><%=Table %><br />";
```

but it doesn't work, it doesn't show any error too, the button just do noting.
I try to delete the <%=Display %> and the <%=Table %> and then it's work so I know it's because that.

how I make it work?

Comment: "Doesn't work". That's not very descriptive of the issue. When you come to Stack Overflow to describe a problem, make sure you provide any error messages or exceptions you get. And make sure you format your code so that it's easily legible. Please update your question.

Comment: Have a look at the source of the page from your browser to see what's been inserted by the `<%=Display %>` and `<%=Table %>` directives. This should help in diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried your code, I got a compilation error. Two of them.

> Error 1   The name 'Display' does not exist in the current
>   context   D:\Visual Studio Projects\WebSite1\Test.aspx    8
>
> Error 2   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table' is a 'type' but is used like
>   a 'variable'  D:\Visual Studio Projects\WebSite1\Test.aspx    8

Let's assume you have public property on your page that the page can access, called Display.

```
public string Display
        {
        get { return "Hello, world!"; }
        }
```

This takes care of Error 1. Unfortunately, Table is the name of a type. So let's change that to MyTable and add a corresponding property. Also, you have to wait until the document is loaded before you can access `div_show` in the DOM. So let's wrap it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(doucument).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("div_show").innerHTML =
    "<br /><div class='font-1'>View Messages:</div><br /><br /><div><%=Display %></div><br /><%=MyTable %><br />";
        });
    </script>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="div_show" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

That gets the value of Display and MyTable into the JavaScript string. But I don't know when exactly you're executing this JavaScript. Let's assume you're using jQuery and the `ready()` function. Then you should get the output as you expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("div_show").innerHTML =
    "<br /><div class='font-1'>View Messages:</div><br /><br /><div><%=Display %></div><br /><%=MyTable %><br />";
        });
    </script>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="div_show" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

If you had posted a more complete question, I could have given you a more concise answer.